# PIs losing wifi connectivity when streaming

Tags: wifi

I have several Raspberry Pi ZeroW's and a 3b+ on my internal LAN with cameras and other toys. All my machines have static IPs. I stream from the Zero W cameras with a simple raspivid command in a service and the 3b+ has motion eye. Everything was fine until I upgraded my WiFi access point from a Cisco 802.11n to a Linksys "smart" Wi-Fi somethingsomething AC. All my Pi's, tablets, COTS web cams, etc moved to the new AP with no issues.

On the old access point I could stream video from the ZeroW's all day and night long. Sometimes the video was delayed several seconds, but rock solid. The 3b+ I could watch the video in a web browser and have no issues.

On the new access point I can only get a minute or two of flaky video before the ZeroW loses connectivity. The 3b+ with motion eye e-mails snapshots when motion is detected and records video locally with no problems. But when I connect with a web browser to watch live vid - I lose the connection within a minute.

They don't crash but they do lose WiFi connectivity and come back after 5 minutes. Without streaming or using something like `wavemon` they are fine. I can leave a constant ping on for hours, leave `htop` running with no issues. My COTS web cams are rock solid and don't miss a beat when streaming.

Searched the web, someone said they had similar issue and turned WMM off. I turned it off - no difference. I have changed the WiFi from mixed (2.4ghz) to n only, 5ghz is disabled, limited the channel width, specified a channel instead of auto, no change.

Checked `dmesg` and see lots of these entries:

```
Jul 18 18:11:05 rpizw00 dhcpcd[437]: wlan0: carrier lost
Jul 18 18:11:05 rpizw00 dhcpcd[437]: wlan0: deleting address fe80:My:IP:6:Address
Jul 18 18:11:05 rpizw00 avahi-daemon[252]: Withdrawing address record for fe80:My:IP:6:Address on wlan0.
Jul 18 18:11:05 rpizw00 avahi-daemon[252]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlan0.IPv6 with address fe80:My:IP:6:Address.
Jul 18 18:11:05 rpizw00 avahi-daemon[252]: Interface wlan0.IPv6 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Jul 18 18:11:05 rpizw00 avahi-daemon[252]: Withdrawing address record for 192.168.1.210 on wlan0.
Jul 18 18:11:05 rpizw00 avahi-daemon[252]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlan0.IPv4 with address 192.168.1.210.
Jul 18 18:11:05 rpizw00 dhcpcd[437]: wlan0: deleting route to 192.168.1.0/24
Jul 18 18:11:05 rpizw00 dhcpcd[437]: wlan0: deleting default route via 192.168.1.250
Jul 18 18:11:05 rpizw00 avahi-daemon[252]: Interface wlan0.IPv4 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Jul 18 18:11:06 rpizw00 dhcpcd[437]: wlan0: carrier acquired
Jul 18 18:11:06 rpizw00 dhcpcd[437]: wlan0: IAID eb:1e:68:c0
Jul 18 18:11:06 rpizw00 dhcpcd[437]: wlan0: adding address fe80:My:IP:6:Address
Jul 18 18:11:06 rpizw00 avahi-daemon[252]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface wlan0.IPv6 with address fe80:My:IP:6:Address.
Jul 18 18:11:06 rpizw00 avahi-daemon[252]: New relevant interface wlan0.IPv6 for mDNS.
Jul 18 18:11:06 rpizw00 avahi-daemon[252]: Registering new address record for fe80:My:IP:6:Address on wlan0.*.
Jul 18 18:11:06 rpizw00 dhcpcd[437]: wlan0: probing address 192.168.1.210/24
Jul 18 18:11:06 rpizw00 dhcpcd[437]: wlan0: soliciting an IPv6 router
Jul 18 18:11:11 rpizw00 dhcpcd[437]: wlan0: using static address 192.168.1.210/24
Jul 18 18:11:11 rpizw00 avahi-daemon[252]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface wlan0.IPv4 with address 192.168.1.210.
Jul 18 18:11:11 rpizw00 dhcpcd[437]: wlan0: adding route to 192.168.1.0/24
Jul 18 18:11:11 rpizw00 dhcpcd[437]: wlan0: adding default route via 192.168.1.250
Jul 18 18:11:11 rpizw00 avahi-daemon[252]: New relevant interface wlan0.IPv4 for mDNS.
Jul 18 18:11:11 rpizw00 avahi-daemon[252]: Registering new address record for 192.168.1.210 on wlan0.IPv4.
Jul 18 18:11:19 rpizw00 dhcpcd[437]: wlan0: no IPv6 Routers available
```

I have 6 different Raspberry PIs connecting wireless. Before replacing the WiFi, they were all streaming fine. Only when I start watching streaming video on a specific PI does it go down, the rest are all fine. I don't have DHCP anywhere on my LAN. Someone posted wlan0 carrier lost might need a keep alive script because the router might be dropping a connection to free up bandwidth. With the constant ping going and losing connection only when I start watching a stream - I don't know. I also have the WiFi power save turned off: `wlan0 set power_save off` so its not WiFi turning off.

My old WiFi was getting old and I needed to upgrade at some point, but this is not much of an upgrade. Any idea where to look to get back to normal operations?

Comment: If it worked BEFORE you changed the router and not after it is unlikely to be the Pi.

Comment: Looks like an issue with the new router.

Comment: @Milliways Not necessarily. It could be that the old router was not using a protocol feature that the new router expects to work, and this feature is misconfigured on the Pi.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev anything is possible but it is difficult to see how the Pi could be responsible for carrier lost

Comment: I really don't know what it is. Put the old wifi back along side the new one and moved one ZeroW over to it. It is still streaming. The newer one has amazing xfer speed 2.2 MB/s compared to the old one with 180KBs. The only thing I see different in wavemon is the new one has a xstation flags: WME even though I have disabled WMM. I will keep searching and try Linksys support even though hopes are not high.